# Maximize equation including vectors and matrices

Tags: r

I'm having trouble figuring out how to solve a maximazation problem in financing.

I want to max: `(t(x)% * %(r)-rf)/(t(x)% * %A% * %x)`
Where `x` is a 3x1 vector, `A` is a 3x3, `rf` is a value (0.02) and `r` is a 3x1 aswell.
From this equation I would like to know the value of `x` that maximize this.

Bonus: If you can insert constraints with all of the individual values in x being between 0 and 1, and to sum to 1 that would be even more awesome

```
sigma1=0.1
sigma2=0.2
sigma3=0.15
korrelationen12=0.25
korrelation23=0.20
korrelation13=0.1
cov12=korrelationen12*sigma1*sigma2
cov13=korrelation13*sigma1*sigma3
cov23=korrelation23*sigma2*sigma3
afkast1=0.04
afkast2=0.12
afkast3=0.08
r=c(afkast1,afkast2,afkast3)
rf=0.02
data=c(sigma1^2,cov12,cov13,cov12,sigma2^2,cov23,cov13,cov23,sigma3^2)
A=matrix(data=data,3,3)
et=c(1,1,1)

max((t(x)% * %(r)-rf)/(t(x)% * %A% * %x),x)????
```

In this example the result has to be the same as I get from using:

```
tangent=(solve(A)%*%(r-(rf)*et))/as.numeric((t(et)%*%solve(A)%*%(r-rf*et)))
tangent
         [,1]
[1,] 0.1320973
[2,] 0.4391657
[3,] 0.4287370
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `optim`:

```
proj <- function(x) x / sum(x) # projection satisfies sum(x) == 1
obj <- function(x) {
 x <- proj(x)
 (t(x)%*%(r)-rf)/(t(x)%*%A%*%x)
}
fit <- optim(proj(1:3), obj, lower = c(0, 0, 0), upper = c(1, 1, 1),
  method = "L-BFGS-B", control = list(fnscale = -1))

proj(fit$par) # parameter values at maximum
## [1] 0.4483085 0.2171453 0.3345461

fit$value # maximum value of objective
## [1] 5.827519
```

Regarding the purported solution at the end of the question note that it is *not* the solution to the maximization question posed since its objective value is less than that shown in the solution above and, therefore, is not the maximizing value:

```
tangent=(solve(A)%*%(r-(rf)*et))/as.numeric((t(et)%*%solve(A)%*%(r-rf*et)))
obj(tangent)
##          [,1]
## [1,] 4.807799
```

Suggest you investigate this inconsistency -- either the question as posed is correct in which `tangent` is not the solution or `tangent` is the solution and there is an error in the question.

Comment: Didn't work out sadly. I forgot to write that when there is none negative values in the original x vector the values has to be the same as I get from the solve-function. The original way of calculating x is: tangent=(solve(A)%*%(r-(rf)*et))/as.numeric((t(et)%*%solve(A)%*%(r-rf*et)))

Comment: Hi G.Grothendieck, I'm not quite sure what you are referring to. I didn't say any of the values were negative. I just said that as long none negative values are produced in the original way of calculating the x-values, the x-values shouldn't change. Besides, I get 0.5895 by inserting the x-values from the 'tangent' and 0.5438 by insterting the values from 'proj(fit$par)' into (t(x)%*%(r)-rf)/(t(x)%*%A%*%x).

Comment: Yeh I get the same as you do, and 4.807799 when using mine. But I have no idea what the objective number tells me, but I can see it only uses information from the vector? It's not x I want to maximize it's the whole expression.

Comment: How can you claim that you solved what I asked to be solved? I didn't ask for you to maximize the objective value of a vector? I asked for the formula to get maximized. I seriously doubt my Professor in Finance and Investment is wrong about this, the wanted x-values are the ones I gave you, not the ones you found. Sorry if my english is inadequate for your standards.

Comment: I have deleted my comments and moved them to the answer.